# How WordPress is able to change locale without using setlocale

Tags: plugins, templates, multi-language, localization, core-modifications

In my plugin I print out the current locales via

```
    $originalLocales = explode(";", setlocale(LC_ALL, 0));

    var_export($originalLocales);die;
```

Obviously the result is same as the `WPLANG`defined.

However, I've grep all the wordpress ' code, I cannot find a single call via `setlocale`, so how WordPress is able to change locale without using setlocale?

Answer (score 0):

I would question "obviously" here. I get rather cryptic string `C` as result on my Windows machine.

Since WP isn't actually using native PHP functionality for any localization and handles it via core code, my best guess would be that is coming from server configuration in your case.